# Why is this part of the jquery source undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, knockout.js, socket.io

I'm building an app using Jquery1.7.1 where the console is getting an error that:

```
for (n = 0; n < r.length; n++) s = r[n], (e || k === s.origType) && (!c || c.guid === s.guid) && (!l || l.test(s.namespace)) && (!d || d === s.selector || d === "**" && s.selector) && (r.splice(n--, 1), s.selector && r.delegateCount--, p.remove && p.remove.call(a, s));
```

Is undefined. I get this error when this is executed:

```
function goToIndex() {
pageView.setCurrentPage(pageView.getIndex());
pageView.setNav(pageView.getIndexNav());
ko.applyBindings(pageView);
}
```

Which doesn't involve jquery so I'm unsure why this is happening. The only jquery related to this is a click handler on the previous function, but that calls a socket.io event which goes to the node.js server and the returning event calls this function.  If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The jQuery source code isn't what's undefined. I don't think you're reading the error message correctly.

Comment: This what the console says: '19:46:10.352 TypeError: s is undefined jquery-1.7.1.js:14'

Comment: and that line is the first part of code

Comment: You have to understand that the parser error happened there. The root cause is almost certainly in your code and NOT your library (i.e. jQuery)

Comment: I do understand that, I'm hoping somebody can point me in the direction of which I should look.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll probably have to use your browser's JavaScript debugger to identify where the problem originated.

Answer (score 1):

The question in your title ("Why is this part of the jQuery source undefined?") has been answered in the comments: no part in the jQuery *source* is undefined, it's merely asked to handle a variable that's undefined.

The question as asked ("Why do I get an "xxx is undefined" error?") isn't answerable, not without more source to reproduce the problem.

In the comments you ask an alternative question: "Can someone point me in the direction of which I should look". @Blazemonger has the answer: look in your JavaScript debugger to identify where the problem originated.

What would certainly help in understanding this problem is to load up the [uncompressed version of your jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js) when you step into the code with your debugger. Based on the snippet of jQuery you posted in the question (specifically "`delegateCount--`"), I'd say the exception is here:

```
// Detach an event or set of events from an element
remove: function( elem, types, handler, selector, mappedTypes ) {
        // ... abbreviated

        // Remove matching events
        for ( j = 0; j < eventType.length; j++ ) {
            handleObj = eventType[ j ];

            if ( ( mappedTypes || origType === handleObj.origType ) &&
                 ( !handler || handler.guid === handleObj.guid ) &&
                 ( !namespaces || namespaces.test( handleObj.namespace ) ) &&
                 ( !selector || selector === handleObj.selector || selector === "**" && handleObj.selector ) ) {
                eventType.splice( j--, 1 );

                if ( handleObj.selector ) {
                    eventType.delegateCount--;
                }
                if ( special.remove ) {
                    special.remove.call( elem, handleObj );
                }
            }
        }

        // ... abbreviated
}
```

Where your compressed `s` variable matches the uncompressed `handleObj` variable. When you enter the debugger there, be sure to check the values of local variables, and if needed go up in the call stack to check where your code is calling jQuery.